# Bootstrap doesn't recognize tr loop used with *ngFor

Tags: html, spring, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm actually stuck in a really strange issue.

Bootsrap responsive table doesn't recognize data when used with  loop *ngFor, but does recognize them when using just  tag.

The page does compile without any errors and the table elements are shown correctly, but bootstrap doesn't recognize it.

I have tried ng-repeat but the result is just a blank page.

```
<table id="datatable-responsive" 
       class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let product of products;">
        <td>
          {{product.productName}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productDesc}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productName}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productDesc}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productName}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productDesc}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productName}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productDesc}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{product.productDesc}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The service product.service.ts :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";


    @Injectable()
    export class ProductService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {


      }

      getAll(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/api/products')

      }

    }
```

The product.component.ts :

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProductService} from "../shared/product/product.service";
    import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-product',
      templateUrl: './product.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
    })
    export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

      products: Array<any>;

      constructor(private productService: ProductService,
                  private route: ActivatedRoute,
                  private router: Router) {}



      ngOnInit() {

        this.productService.getAll().subscribe(data => { 
    this.products=data;});

      }
    }
```

Comment: Are your imports in module correct? You sure it just doesn't recognise _*ngFor_ itself? If I'm not mistaken _*ngFor_ is part of _CommonModule_ which should be imported in *app.module.ts*

Comment: *ngFor works and the results shows the table populated without any issue the problem is with the bootstrap responsive table shows "no data available in table" but when i use the tr tag without the loop it shows "1 entrie".

Comment: Any chance you could replicate this issue in a snippet?

Comment: Or add a condition on table *ngIf="isDataLoaded". By default isDataLoaded=false.
set isDataLoaded to true when data received from API.

Comment: @MukeshKumar can u explain more ... i did try that *ngIF="isDataLoaded" in the table but it didn't workout

Comment: Can you share your component's HTML and ts file code?

Comment: Is this AngularJS (Angular v1) or Angular (Angular v2+)? You are using `ng-controller`, which is AngularJS and `*ngFor`, which is Angular. You can't mix AngularJS and Angular syntax in one Html page.

Comment: @Deborahk thanks for the reply ... well im not using ng-controller ... im on Angular and using a component with a service to provide the data ...no ng-controller used.

Comment: @Deborahk the use of the ng-controller was just a suggestion made to me by a friend to fix the issue but it didn't work ... im not using ng-controller in my solution.
this is the code im using to provide the data :
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Array<any>;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getAll().subscribe(data => { this.products=data;});
  }
}

Comment: It is really hard to read code pasted into comments. Please update the question instead with the revised or added code.

Comment: @Deborahk i've updated the question with the revised code.

Comment: @redafaghloumi please also add the code of your component ts file

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar I've added the component ts file
PS :  i did try to use *ngIf="products" on the table tag so that the table doesn't render tell the data is loaded, but it causes the pagination and the table options to vanish  ..

Comment: @redafaghloumi, I have executed your code in stackblitz and it is working fine. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tewjxj

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar, as i have explained in my question the code does execute and even the data get shown the problem is in the bootstrap (pagination .. search ...) those options don't work.

Comment: @redafaghloumi, Are you using jquery datatable with bootstrap styles?

Comment: @redafaghloumi, I have updated the stackbliz code. Please take a look.

Comment: @MukeshKumar, thanks for your help i did find the dependency responsible of this Bug, i've compared your dpendencies with the one i'm using and eleminated evrything one by one, it was a jquery dpendency that interfaired with the use of my app.
not sure if it was this way cause the jquery was delraed in the end of the page not in the head ... but for certain getting it out corrected my bug.